# Git clone working on one location and not another

Tags: git

I want to clone a bare repository \Server\LocationZ\Z into another server location \Server...\Y

```
cd '\\Server\...\Y'
git clone '\\Server\LocationZ\Z' 'myClone'
```

The issue is that it does not work and I get the following error message

```
fatal: update_ref failed for ref 'HEAD': cannot update ref 'refs/heads/master': trying to write ref 'refs/heads/master' with nonexistent object 2588da1d204d92886031cd0aa4aa88947eb7dd61
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Now, if I clone into another location on the server, it works just fine :

```
cd '\\Server\...\X'
git clone '\\Server\LocationZ\Z' 'myClone'
```

**What could be causing this ?**

I checked read/write permissions, they seem fine. Path length is more or less equivalent for both locations. Both locations are stored on the same server.

Comment: Maybe a timeout from your server?

Comment: Same server so I guess it should not work on both then. And tried it multiple times

Comment: The most interesting part of this is the "nonexistent object" complaint, which suggests that while your `git clone` is busy *writing to* `...\X\myClone,` something else is going behind its back and *removing from* `...\X\myClone`.